# Format a permanent-data SD Card

Tags: disk-formatting

I want to make a bootable pen drive of windows. I have a 64-GB SD Card in which I want to make it. But it is not formatting. The files are all coming back. I think it's not corrupted. Can you please help me ?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What are the exact commands you are running to make the pen drive?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 x64
I am making the pen drive with Balena Etcher but the moment it is completed it is showing an error.

Comment: Due to the Microsoft ISOs incompatibility with most tools you need to use MKUSB: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue would be the physical write protection switch on the side of the card is preventing writes - toggle the switch and try again.

SD cards are notoriously unreliable - check `dmesg` and `journalctl` to see if any error messages appear when inserting the card. Also use `badblock` to see if the card is experiencing any read/write errors.

Comment: Thanks, but all are ok. The data in the SD Card is coming again, after deleting all the files and taking out and mounting it again.